# Access a share on a server using another servername

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage, network-share, unc

We've recently moved to a new office, and merged our network with a bigger one (Trust between our domains), and now we are using the storage box of the bigger network.

This poses a problem for me:
My clients are used to access the storage box via UNC path: \MyStorage\file.doc
Now, to access the same files, they'll need to access: \StorageServer\MyStorage\file.doc

This boils down to - I'd like to link a servername+sharename to a different servername.
What can I do for this to happen?

I was looking at dfs (link \StorageServer\MyStorage -> MyStorage), but that alone doesn't seem help

Note: I'd rather not touch the storage box, and limit myself to changes to my domain only.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you mapping shares as network drives using GPO logon script? If so I would update the logon script to point to the new path

Comment: I am mapping drives, but I can't rely on it - clients could have used the UNC path version

Answer (score 0):

Take the IP address of your old storage server and add it to the new one. As long as none of the shares on the old top level shares have the same name on the new server, you'll be ok. If they do, it gets more complex.

This is how I'd do it on a NAS, at least. I presume it works the same way with Windows file servers.

Comment: The old storage is now a folder on the new storage (with other folders for different departments), so it won't help - I'm still stuck with a level of indirection (\\A\B instead of \\B)

Comment: You can make all the old top level folders top level folders on the new storage, is what I'm saying. So if your old storage included \\B\sales, you could create a "sales" share on \\A\ and make the old IP address for B point to it.